# Can I make OpenOffice.org recognize automatically the language I am writing in?

Tags: openoffice.org, language-support, dictionary

I use to write a lot in many different languages, and I frequently use spelling checkers to correct my texts. But switching the settings manually each time is a loss of time.

In Firefox I have a very useful extension called [Dictionary Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3414/) which automatically detects the language I am writing in and suggests corrections. Does OpenOffice.org have an equivalent of this feature? If yes, how do I install it and/or change the settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from [this brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/10469/) and [this post](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=48938) on the OpenOffice.org forums, there is no support for automatic language detection in OO.o. However, an idea suggested on the brainstorm might be of use; if you change keyboard layouts to that of your target language, apparently OpenOffice.org will use that as the spell-check language.

Comment: 1. Most people don't switch keyboards when switching languages inside a document, 2. Keyboard layouts and languages are (often) not related, so changing languages on keyboard layout changes is a bad idea.

Comment: If they have a multilingual keyboard layout, then they wouldn't have to swap physical keyboards. I'm not arguing that that OpenOffice functionality makes sense, just mentioning it in case it happens to work well for this user.

Answer (score 0):

Install **xneur** from standard repositories. It allow auto-switching of keyboard layout on system level (and inside OpenOffice too, of course).